# Use Stream return type in Spring Boot controller lead to "java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, streaming, ojdbc, oracle19c

When streaming result from JpaRepository to Rest API, I have an exception "java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next"

I am Using Spring boot, Spring Data JPA and Oracle Database/JDBC

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Stream<Entity> findAllByFilter(String filter);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class EntityService {
  @Autowired private EntityRepository repository;

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Stream<Entity> getEntityByFilter(String filter) {
    return repository.findAllByFilter(filter);
  }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/entities")
public class EntityController {

  @Autowired private EntityService service;

  @GetMapping(value = "/filter/{filter}")
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Stream<Entity> getEntitiesByFilter(@PathVariable("filter") String filter) {
    return service.getEntityByFilter(filter);
  }
}
```

Consuming the stream in the controller works, but returning it through HTTP cause

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next  at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.ensureOpen(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:201)
> ~[ojdbc11-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]    at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:496)
> ~[ojdbc11-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:101)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.ScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(ScrollableResultsIterator.java:33)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]     at
> java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:132) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by using getResultStream of Query class and applying my filters with Predicates (instead of JpaRepository), the Stream to a HTTP client work well